# Change default Webdev.Webserver Physical Path on a VS2008 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, webdev.webserver

I think I've seen this done once, but I cannot find it again after a long Googling/Binging session!

I'd like to create a new ASP.NET MVC project, then create a folder "Web" inside the project, and move all the "web-related" files to inside this folder.

The problem is that when creating this folder structure, I cannot simply press "F5" to start the Webdev.Webserver, because the "physical path" of my application is still pointing to my project root folder.

In the project settings, I've found the configurations for the development server, where I can change the port, for example, but there's no option to specify the "physical path".

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to separate Web-related files from, say, Domain-related files, the best you have to do is to created separate projects inside the same solution.

Let's say you create a Store solution. You could then create different projects called Store.Web, Store.Domain, Store.Test, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message, but I don't want different projects. I'd like to have only one project, but with different folders for Web, Domain. They will be different namespaces, but I'd like to have them all on the same assembly.